# Octave: Set matrix values according to vector

Tags: octave

How do you set values of a matrix according to a different vector?

For example, if I had a matrix M

```
M = 
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0
```

and a vector V

```
V = 
  2
  4
  3 
  4
```

How do you set the element in every row with the column given by vector V?

For example if I wanted to set it to 1, the output would be:

```
M = 
  0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1
  0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 1
```

I am able to get the values of the elements in each row with the column given by the vector using
`M'(V)`
but it does not allow me to set those values.

When I try to set those values, `M'(V)=1` for example, it says `invalid lvalue`.

Is it possible to set the values of a matrix with the columns given by a vector?